# Execute C++ program from Perl script; does it require a compiler?

Tags: c++, perl, header-files

I have a somewhat more complicated question this time. I have written a short Perl program where my final ouput is in an array. I want to execute a C++ script with a .hpp file extension within my Perl script on each element of my output (I have downloaded the source code from the UCSC Genome Browser). This is really difficult for me since I'm a beginner in programming overall and don't know anything about C++.  I've done some reading and I think the best for me would be to use a qx call. I've tried that and it just opens the .hpp file in the text editor when I run my Perl script. I'm not sure if this is because I've erroneoulsy assigned the .hpp file extension to be opened with Editor or whether I need a compiler to run .hpp files in general.

```
my $info = qx(primercheck.hpp);
print "primercheck.hpp is: $info\n";
```

Comment: I've just realised I haven't strictly asked a question... So; do I need a compiler to execute a C++ .hpp file from a Perl program? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: "C++ script" - is it a script, or is it source code?

Comment: Then generally speaking it will need to be compiled into some form of executable (Unless you find a program that will correctly interpret your source code as a script and execute it, in which case you should run that program, passing it your source file. There isn't a standard way to do this, you will rely on third party applications).

Comment: Ok, thank you! I'll read up on that.

Comment: You may find Inline::CPP useful, although it still requires a compiler, and a reasonable understanding of how to work within the landscape of its target language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `.hpp` file is a header file, that generally contains just macros and declarations, not executable code. It is used to specify the interface to code in `.cpp` files and cannot be compiled on its own.

A typical C++ program consists of several `.cpp` and `.hpp` files that must be compiled in combination and then linked with each other and with library files to create an executable image.

So yes, you do need a compiler, and a lot more besides!

Comment: Oh, well... In that case I'll do some extensive reading before I try anything else. I was just hoping for an easier way so I don't have to learn too much about C++ :) Thanks a lot though!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are on *nix, you could use the `gcc` tool to first compile the source code at runtime, via a `system` call from your perl script, and then make another system call to run the generated executable file.

Also, further to Borodin's answer, even if your file with the `hpp` extension has executable code, it may get compiled but will not execute. A workaround would be to make a temporary copy of the source and give it a `cpp` extension and compile it, to get an executable which you can call from your perl script. However, this requires your `hpp` file to actually have executable code if you want any output. Here's an example,

```
# make a temp copy with cpp extension
system("cp primercheck.hpp primercheck.cpp");

# generate executable using gcc
system("gcc -o primercheck primercheck.cpp");

# set execute permissions on resulting file
system("chmod +x primercheck");

# call the executable
system("./primercheck");

# remove the temp cpp file
system("rm primercheck.cpp");

# optional - remove the executable file as well
system("rm primercheck");
```

Hope this helps.